# (Xamarin) TabbedPage padding isn't doing intended effect (no padding on top)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, padding, tabbedpage

Within my TabbedPage

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JobMotivator"
            x:Class="PlaceHolder.MainTabbedPage"

                Padding="left,top,right,bottom">
```

I want padding on all sides except the top so the content page that is selected is sitting flush against the tabs. No matter which order I do, it's resulting in unintended effect.

if left = 0, with top, right and bottom = 10, it results in:

[image: The Left being against the screen]

if top = 10, with left, right and bottom = 10, and if bottom = 0, with left, top and right = 10, it results in:

[image: The Bottom being against the screen]

if right = 0, with left, top and bottom = 10, it results in: The Top and Right side being against the screen, with left having 10 and the bottom having 20

[image: The Top and Right side being against the screen, with left having 10 and the bottom having 20]

Why is it, when I try to set the top variable (b) to anything that isn't equal to all the other 3, it results in unintended effects? (b value becomes bottom instead of top, or if I do c, top and right aren't working correctly)

Comment: It would be easier if you added screenshots of the various combinations of paddings, instead of describing it. A real boon would be some kind of image of what you would expect.

Comment: Screenshots have been added

Comment: did you try setting padding directly on contentpages inside tabbed page? i think that padding on tabbedpage doesnt work but it works contentpages inside tabbedpage